# How to change manage permission send message to false for many roles in private channel discord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i make private channel from my server discord, so only certain roles can send message, and the name roles is Verified, Member TCR, and FRZ

and this is my code

````
async def lock(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    perms = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    perms.send_messages=False
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Leader")
    
    if role in author.roles:
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=perms)
        await ctx.send("Channel Locked")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have permission to lock channel")

@client.command()
async def unlock(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    perms = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
    perms.send_messages=True
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name="Leader")
    if role in author.roles:
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=perms)
        await ctx.send("Channel Unlocked")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have permission to unlock channel")```

what the codes for change send message = False for role Verified, Member TCR, and FRZ
````

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please help us understand what your issue is, we can't do much with just the code. Is it returning an error? Is it not doing anything?

Answer (score 1):

### Change permissions for many roles at once

###### You have 2 different solutions to get your roles:

---

1. If your [channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel) is in a [category](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel), you can get [role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role)s that have inherited [permission](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions)s from this [category](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel) doing the following:

```py
channel_permissions = ctx.channel.overwrites

target_roles = channel_permissions.keys()
```

2. Otherwise you can change [permission](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions)s for **each** [role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role)s in your [guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild)

```py
target_roles = ctx.guild.roles
```

###### Set permissions to your roles:

---

```py
# ! Dont forget to add one of the target_roles code above here

# This is the role that will still have permissions in the channel
channel_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Verified")

new_overwrites = dict()
for role in target_roles:
    # [Deny] all permissions for the current 'role'
    new_overwrites[role] = discord.PermissionOverwrite.from_pair(discord.Permissions.none(), discord.Permissions.all())

# [Allow] few permissions to your target role
new_overwrites[channel_role] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(
    add_reactions=True,
    attach_files=True,
    embed_links=True,
    view_channel=True,
    send_messages=True,
)

# apply to the channel new_overwrites (permissions corresponding to each targeted roles)
await ctx.channel.edit(overwrites=new_overwrites)
```

###### Documentation can be found here:

---

- [Channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [Category](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel)
- [Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild)
- [Permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions)
- [PermissionOverwrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PermissionOverwrite)
- [PermissionOverwrite.from_pair](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PermissionOverwrite.from_pair)
- [Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role)